# Howto configure Realtek ALC1150 ? Issue: line out gives mono sound only

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have followed multiple posts here as well as https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto, but it seems issues with audio chipsets are often quite particular.

My system has an ASUS P10S-WS motherboard with 7.1 audio. I have stereo speakers connected to the line out, which is one of the output pins on the back (the lime one, or Front Speaker out when connected in a surround setup). The problem is that this gives mono sound only, so output on only one speaker. If I connect the headphone jack on the front of the computer, stereo output is ok, so the speakers work.

The system is a regular Ubuntu 18.04, latest available updates and kernel installed (4.15.0-23-generic).

My current actions and results:

- I checked and double checked the correct profile is loaded, using sound settings as well as pavucontrol. I have tried both stereo out and stereo duplex.
- I have tried loading the module specifying different models as described in the guide above, but unfortunately the ALC1150 is not available. I have tried several ASUS profiles and some generic ones. Some models disabled sound, so I know at least these actions must have changed the driver configuration.
- I have used hdajackretask to remap the output pin. This was the only action so far that gave a result: I was able to get output on the second speaker, but is was heavily distorted. I must admit I'm not really sure what I'm doing here, I have tried to remap it to various line out and headphones entries in the drop down list.

Some details from alsa:

pactl list cards

```
Card #3
Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3
Driver: module-alsa-card.c
Owner Module: 10
Properties:
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf620000 irq 160"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "a170"
    device.product.name = "Sunrise Point-H HD Audio"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "0"
    device.description = "Built-in Audio"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci">
```

cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | head

```
Codec: Realtek ALC1150
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x10ec0900
Subsystem Id: 0x1043868f
Revision Id: 0x100001
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x5f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
```

I'd just like to know how this works and what I can do about it. Any takers?